# Change target of all links inside an iframe to "_parent" jquery

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, iframe, parent

im trying to set the target to all links inside an iframe to "_parent" using jquery but im not sure how to do it, can anyone help me?

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js">
$('a').target("_parent");
</script>  

<iframe src="http://google.com" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Im doing this because I want to customize my firefox 4 homepage to show me the Google's start page with the restore session button near the "Sign in" link, and I almost do it but i don't wanna open the new links or searches inside the iframe.

Thanks

P.S. If is there another way without using jquery it would be great.

Answer (score 4):

It's

```
$('a').attr("target", "_parent");
```

There's no method in jQuery called `target()` ;) Read about the `attr` method in jQuery - http://api.jquery.com/attr/

To go along with that, you should have the two `<script />` tags separate.

```
<script src="jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').attr("target", "_parent");
</script>
```

And just so you know, you cannot access the content of an `iframe` if its content is hosted on a different domain than its parent document.

Answer (score 3):

It might be noted that you could do this without scripting anything with a base tag

```
<base target="_parent">
```

in the head.